# How to numerically minimize sum of squared errors in regression analysis in Matrix form

Tags: r

So i need to do a matrix calculation (which I did already, heres the code)

```
> incomeX=c(35,90,47,45,68,70,55)
> engelY=c(21,8,16,14,11,12,10)
> Y=engelY
> X=cbind(rep(1,times=length(incomeX)),incomeX)
> solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y
        [,1]
        24.71247
incomeX -0.19753
```

But now i need to do this same calculation while numerically minimizing sum of squared errors. Any ideas?

One thing that may be helpful is that (epsilon hat=X*beta hat-Y) (sorry i dont know how to do the symbols)

- Also `> betahat=solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y`

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.magesblog.com/post/2013-03-12-how-to-use-optim-in-r/
If you have to do it all by yourself, you could code up a function of the newton-raphson algorithm and run such that it minimizes epsilon by varying beta hat.

Comment: awesome! i was able to figure it out, i didnt end up using the matrix representation because i couldn't figure it out, maybe if u know?, but i did get the answer i was looking for ty